# How to pass a date variable into a php query

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying many different ways to pass the dates into the query as a variable, and nothing I've tried has worked. When I put the exact dates in there like below, the query works fine.

```
$ly = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT SUM(rtype_price) FROM client WHERE date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-12-31"');

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ly))
  {
    $ly_cash = $row1['SUM(rtype_price)'];
  }
```

For example, I've been trying something like this:

```
$ly_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of previous year'));
$ly_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous year'));
```

then passing $ly_start and $ly_end into the query like this:

```
$ly = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT SUM(rtype_price) FROM client WHERE date BETWEEN "$ly_start" AND "$ly_end"');
```

Comment: Concatenation problem : `BETWEEN "'.$ly_start.'" AND "'.$ly_end.'"'`

Comment: You will never get the value as expected if you put a variable inside a single quote. ` "$ly_start" AND "$ly_end"` will out put something like ` "$ly_start" AND "$ly_end"` not `YYYY-mm-dd AND YYYY-MM-DD` as expected,

Comment: Wow, so simple. That was the trick, inverting the single/double quotes. Starting with "SELECT instead of 'SELECT and then the date variables as '$ly_start' worked. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Inverting the quotes did the trick. This works:

```
$ly = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT SUM(rtype_price) FROM client WHERE paid = 1 AND date BETWEEN '$ly_start' AND '$ly_end'");
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ly))
  {
    $ly_cash = $row1['SUM(rtype_price)'];
  }
```

Thank you ild_flue

Comment: ever heard of prepared statements?